# Where is likely the performance bug here?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, linq, optimization

Many of the test cases are timing out. I've made sure I'm using lazy evaluation everywhere, linear (or better) routines, etc. I'm shocked that this is still not meeting the performance benchmarks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Mine
{
    public int Distance { get; set; } // from river
    public int Gold { get; set; } // in tons
}

class Solution 
{
    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        // helper function for reading lines
        Func<string, int[]> LineToIntArray = (line) => Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(' '), Int32.Parse);

        int[] line1 = LineToIntArray(Console.ReadLine());
        int N = line1[0], // # of mines
            K = line1[1]; // # of pickup locations

        // Populate mine info
        List<Mine> mines = new List<Mine>();
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            int[] line = LineToIntArray(Console.ReadLine());
            mines.Add(new Mine() { Distance = line[0], Gold = line[1] });
        }

        // helper function for cost of a move
        Func<Mine, Mine, int> MoveCost = (mine1, mine2) => 
            Math.Abs(mine1.Distance - mine2.Distance) * mine1.Gold;

        int sum = 0; // running total of move costs

        // all move combinations on the current list of mines, 
        // given by the indicies of the mines
        var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, N); 
        var moves = from i1 in indices
                    from i2 in indices
                    where i1 != i2
                    select new int[] { i1, i2 };

        while(N != K) // while number of mines hasn't been consolidated to K
        {           
            // get move with the least cost
            var cheapest = moves.Aggregate(
                (prev, cur) => MoveCost(mines[prev[0]],mines[prev[1]]) 
                                   < MoveCost(mines[cur[0]], mines[cur[1]])
                               ? prev : cur
            );

            int i = cheapest[0], // index of source mine of cheapest move
                j = cheapest[1]; // index of destination mine of cheapest move

            // add cost to total
            sum += MoveCost(mines[i], mines[j]);

            // move gold from source to destination          
            mines[j].Gold += mines[i].Gold;

            // remove from moves any that had the i-th mine as a destination or source
            moves = from move in moves
                    where move[0] == i || move[1] == i
                    select move;

            // update size number of mines after consolidation
            --N;    
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use your profiler to figure out what’s expensive.

Comment: On a quick first glance, if `N` is like 1,000,000 then `moves` is going to be on the order of 10^12 in size. Other than that, it's hard to say anything without more info. (While we're at it, that is most definitely NOT linear)

Comment: We're not here to debug your app for you.  You haven't even told us what it is supposed to do.  [mcve]

Comment: The performance bug is definitely the way you use `moves` variable inside the loop, creating a recursive chain of deferred execution queries with unknown depth.

Comment: @lc why would you say it is not linear? a but confused as what is meant here

Comment: @Neil This is about the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of OP’s code. The construction of `moves` alone cannot happen in linear time, since it’s creating an enumerable of quadratic size (it’s being created lazily, but that does not mean that the instructions won’t run N² times). And it’s getting worse inside the `while` loop…

Comment: Just to give you an idea, you can use the [Stopwatch class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) to find out how long does your block of code runs. This is a good start for isolating which codes are expensive.

Comment: I would look at linear programming with recursion

Comment: I will point out that had you actually used the code I'd suggested in your previous question, you wouldn't have this problem. You'd still have the O(N^2) cost of generating the moves, but after that the cost is O(N). Your insistence on repeating the query with each iteration is killing your performance.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Answer (score 7):

Lazy evaluation will not make bad algorithms perform better. It will just *delay* when those performance problems will affect you. What lazy evaluation *can* help with is space complexity, i.e. reducing the amount of memory you need to execute your algorithm. Since the data is generated lazily, you will not (necessarily) have all the data in the memory at the same time.

However, relying on lazy evaluation to fix your space (or time) complexity problems can easily shoot you in the foot. Look the following example code:

```
var moves = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(x => {
    Console.WriteLine("Generating");
    return x;
});

var aggregate = moves.Aggregate((p, c) => {
    Console.WriteLine("Aggregating");
    return p + c;
});

var newMoves = moves.Where(x => {
    Console.WriteLine("Filtering");
    return x % 2 == 0;
});

newMoves.ToList();
```

As you can see, both the `aggregate` and the `newMoves` rely on the lazily evaluated `moves` enumerable. Since the original count of `moves` is 5, we will see 4 “Aggregating” lines in the output, and 5 “Filtering” lines. But how often do you expect “Generating” to appear in the console?

**The answer is 10.** This is because `moves` is a generator and is being evaluated lazily. When multiple places request it, an iterator will be created for each, which ultimately means that the generator will execute multiple times (to generate independent results).

This is not necessarily a problem, but in your case, it very quickly becomes one. Assume that we continue above example code with another round of aggregating. That second aggregate will consume `newMoves` which in turns will consume the original `moves`. So to aggregate, we will re-run the original `moves` generator, and the `newMoves` generator. And if we were to add another level of filtering, the next round of aggregating would run three interlocked generators, again rerunning the original `moves` generator.

Since your original `moves` generator creates an enumerable of quadratic size, and has an *actual time complexity* of `O(n²)`, this is an actual problem. With each iteration, you add another round of filtering which will be linear to the size of the `moves` enumerable, and you actually consume the enumerable completely for the aggregation. So you end up with `O(n^2 + n^3 + n^4 + n^5 + …)` which will eventually be the sum of `n^j` for `j` starting at `2` up to `N-K`. That is a *very bad* time complexity, and all just because you were trying to save memory by evaluating the moves lazily.

So the first step to make this better is to avoid lazy evaluation. You are constantly iterating `moves` and filtering it, so you should have it in memory. Yes, that means that you have an array of quadratic size, but you won’t actually need more than that. This also limits the time complexity you have. Yes, you still need to filter the list in linear time (so `O(n²)` since the size is n²) and you do that inside a loop, so you will end up with cubic time (`O(n³)`) but that would already be your upper limit (iterating the list a constant amount of times within the loop will only increase the time complexity by a constant, and that doesn’t matter).

Once you have done that, you should consider your original problem, think about what you are actually doing. I believe you could probably reduce the computational complexity further if you use the information you have better, and use data structures (e.g. hash sets, or some graph where the move cost is already stored within) that aid you in the filtering and aggregation. I can’t give you exact ideas since I don’t know your original problem, but I’m sure there is something you can do.

Finally, if you have performance problems, always remember to profile your code. The profiler will tell you what parts of your code is the most expensive, so you can get a clear idea what you should try to optimize and what you don’t need to focus on when optimizing (since optimizing already fast parts will not help you get any faster).